# OEL fresh install while keeping old LogVols

Tags: linux, redhat, lvm, oracle, partition

I've been asked to install OEL 5.x on a server and setup a disk with a few directories (there's only one disk in the server). So I have an OEL 5.x server wtih multiple log volumes in a volume group:

```
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /                        ext3    defaults        1 1
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol03 /storage/z11             ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol02 /staged                  ext3    defaults        1 2
```

After the DBAs upgrade Oracle and do other magic, they ask that I install OEL 6.x on the server while preserving the data they have in LogVol02 and LogVol03. What's the best way to install OEL 6.x without destroying this data?

Comment: Upgrading from 5 to 6 is not supported by Oracle - so don't do it.  You need to back up your data, do a fresh OS install, and then restore the data.

Comment: I'm not upgrading, I'm fresh installing 6. I already won that battle with them, they kept insisting to "upgrade to 6". I finally got the machine to "upgrade" to 6 by messing with the source code of the installer but it still failed everywhere after installation (all kinds of goofy errors -- just like I told them would happen) and they finally let me clean install.  Anyway they need to keep those partitions LogVol02 and 03. They don't want to restore the data because it takes too long and they will be out of their production down time window.

Comment: Please show the full output of `fdisk -l` and `df -h`.

Comment: Would the system crash if you simply set the yum repository to 6.5 (public-yum.oracle.com) and told it `yum update -y`? Just wondering...

Comment: There are too many changes from 5 to 6 and they are not compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the installer asks you how to partition the disks, choose a custom layout. The installer will [show you](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/resources/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/images/diskpartitioning/ddmain.png) your existing drives, partitions, volume groups, and logical volumes. Select */dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00* and choose [edit](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/resources/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/images/diskpartitioning/part-add.png). Tell it to format it and use it for */*. Similarly choose to edit */dev/VolGroup00/LogVol02* and */dev/VolGroup00/LogVol02*. Tell the installer **not** to format them, and tell it where to mount them.

This is documented in [section 9.15 Creating a Custom Layout or Modifying the Default Layout](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-diskpartitioning-x86.html)  in RHEL's installation guide. Since OEL is mostly a RHEL clone the same information should apply.

Answer (score 0):

I think oracle linux use anaconda installation programm as redhat linux, first backup your data, in the installation step "partitioning or something like this", choose manualy partition or similar options, from there you can skeep the volume format